# Disk based implementation of List

Tags: java, list, local-storage, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Collection which pages to disk when it gets full?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773864/java-collection-which-pages-to-disk-when-it-gets-full)

I want a disk based implementation of List.
It would be great if it can store N elements in RAM and rest in disk

Comment: You're either looking for the `File` interface or a JDBC, to use a database.

Comment: but got a different answer :D

Answer (score 5):

You can try experimenting with [Ehcache](http://ehcache.org), there should be an option to overflow cached objects to disk. If you are thinking about disk storage just because of huge memory usage consider using vanilla-java collection implementation: [HugeCollections](http://code.google.com/p/vanilla-java/wiki/HugeCollections)

Comment: HugeCollections is not flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). It serialize any object graph as XML and has option to persist collections (lists, sets, maps) on disk.