# Looking for a java.util.List implementation which can handle huge data

Tags: java

I am trying to fix OOM problem of a legacy system.
After some analyzing, I find it may query huge data from database, and store them in an ArrayList.
But because most documents are lost, we can't do too many modifications.

So I want to look for an List implementation, which can handle huge data.
For example: I can store all data in a file, and just keep 1000 elements in memory. If the iterator or get() try to access data that is not in the memory, it can automatically retrieve data from the disk.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use the List to do things that the database should be doing. You may be focusing your energies on the wrong thing. Consider instead improving the use of the database so that your program doesn't have the requirement of putting a huge amount of information in a List.

Answer (score 1):

A `List` is what it says - a list of data that can be either bounded (Array) or unbounded (ArrayList/LinkedList etc). Hence, there is nothing of a list type that can handle **huge** data especially when **huge** is undefined or not defined clearly.

There can be the following approaches :

1. Consider using a configurable limit that can be used to paginate the data coming from the database. Every time your application would be guaranteed to read at most these many rows from the database and hence return them as linked lists.
2. If possible evaluate the usage of the code -   under what conditions would this code get called? Also, is there a pre-mature optimization of pre-loading data from a database with an intent to avoid subsequent DB calls while searching for a value?  If these conditions are true - then IMO, this premature optimization must be removed; you can query for a particular range of keys in the database and DB technlogies are mature enough to handle this well. If this change is not possible then a B-Tree like data structure would be more helpful where-in the keys are the primary keys of the rows loaded from the database. You would actually retrieve for the data from the database only if the search key is present within this created tree.
3. The last and most un-recommended (but worst-case) option is to tune the JVM memory parameters to be able to accommodate the data. However, this is a fragile and time-consuming process and guaranteed to fail sooner or later

To summarize - every data structure and system has it's limits in terms of the memory and other computing resources that can be available to it. It is hence important to understand the current functionality and limitations of the system under test and then develop an appropriate solution to scale your application.

Hope this helps you towards a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I agree. However, it is a legacy system, we don't have the complete documents, we don't have complete source codes neither. So we have to find a way to fix the OOM problem without changing the original architecture too much. Thanks for any further suggestion.

Comment: @LeonChen Did you check the link mentioned in the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773864/java-collection-which-pages-to-disk-when-it-gets-full ?